# Visualization for comparing max,min and avg in power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I want to show comparing of these value in line chart : max-min and average(actual value)
Assuming we have these three values without thinking to the data structure

Is there a similar visualization like image attached below  in power bi or maybe other tools?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

@sourabmaity u could use heirachial bar chart for this type of scenario. u can find it in custom visuals.